# %TIMESTAMP% in WinSCP scripting is not resolved

Tags: datetime, command-line, ssis, winscp

I have script that will download the files from SFTP server to Windows using execute command in SSIS with `winscp.exe` as my executable. But I need the datetime stamp from the previous date in my file.

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://username:password@10.10.20.20/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
get "/app/informatica/infaadm/9.5.1/server/infa_shared/BID/testing.csv" "D:\SSIS_Test\testing_%TIMESTAMP%.csv"
close
```

But when I ran the execute command only `testing_%TIMESTAMP%.csv` is generated in the target folder.

Comment: What version of WinSCP are you using? Enable logging (`winscp.exe /log=c:\writable\path\to\winscp.log /script=...`) and show us the log.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct.

If the file is indeed downloaded to a file named `testing_%TIMESTAMP%.csv`, it must be because you are using a version of WinSCP that does not support the [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp).

I.e. a [version older than 5.6.2](https://winscp.net/tracker/1223).

[Download](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%
```

I hope help you.